# Is Riesz Lemma really necessary?

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces

It is known that a normed space $X$ is finite dimensional iff the unit sphere is compact.
This is usually proved by means of Riesz's lemma. I came up with the following proof, that does not use it (although the idea is fairly similar) and I'd like to know if it actually works.

First, suppose that $X$ is not complete: it is known then that the unit sphere is not complete, and thus not compact; Moreover, since every finite dimensional space is complete, $X$ is not finite-dimensional.

Now, suppose $X$ is complete:
Take $x:||x||=1$. Now take another vector with unit norm $y$ such that $y$ and $x$ are linearly independent. Now let $Y=\text{span}(x,y)$: since it is clearly finite dimensional, it is complete.
Being a complete subspace of a complete vector space, it is a closed subspace. We now consider
$d_Y(y,\text{span}(x))=\inf_{z\in\text{span}(x)}d(y,z)$: as we are in a finite dimensional subspace, we know that the $\inf$ is actually obtained. Let
$\hat x$ be so that $d( y, \hat x)=d(y,\text{span}(x))$. It is then easy to see that $x_1:=\frac{y-\hat{x}}{||y-\hat x||}$ has necessarily distance $=1$ from $\text{span}(x)$. Iterating this process, we get a sequence $x,x_1,\dots, x_n,\dots$  of vectors such that $||x_i||=1, d(x_i,x_j)\ge 1$, and thus the unit sphere is not compact.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Normally, you say that the unit *ball* is compact, although I suppose the two are equivalent, since the sphere is a closed subset of the ball, and the ball is a cone of the sphere.

Comment: Also note that you don't actually use completeness in the main part of your argument. A complete subspace of any metric space (or, indeed, any uniform space) is closed. This is very easy to show.